# Ошибка запуска exe файла созданного с помощью pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Из python скрипта создал exe файл при помощи pyinstaller. Использовал команду: pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --collect-all reportlab.graphics.barcode script.py (т.к. изначально exe файл ругался на отсутствие reportlab.graphics.barcode).
Но теперь exe файл стал ругаться на отсутствие libdmtx-64.dll. Сама dll на лежит на диске по пути ...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pylibdmtx
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно скомпилировать exe, чтобы не итоговый файл не ругался на отсутствие libdmtx-64.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы включить libdmtx-64.dll в итоговый exe файл при использовании PyInstaller, вам нужно указать опцию `--add-binary` при вызове команды. Это позволит скопировать указанный файл в папку сборки приложения. В вашем случае, вы также можете указать опцию `--hidden-import=libdmtx` для того, чтобы явно включить модуль libdmtx в процесс компиляции.

Вот как будет выглядеть команда для компиляции с учетом libdmtx-64.dll:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --collect-all reportlab.graphics.barcode --add-binary "C:\путь_к_файлу\libdmtx-64.dll;." --hidden-import=libdmtx script.py
```

Где C:\путь_к_файлу\libdmtx-64.dll замените на полный путь к файлу libdmtx-64.dll на вашем компьютере.

Таким образом, при запуске итогового exe файла, libdmtx-64.dll должен быть доступен и не вызывать ошибку об отсутствии